# VSCode only targets old verson of Illustrator (CS6)

Tags: visual-studio-code, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I recently moved to a new workstation and cannot target an Adobe Application using VSCode and Extendscript Debugger.  The workstaton previously had CS 6 installed on it, but now we use CC.  I'm using Ilustrator 2019.

I can target Illustrator:
[Target Menu Works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9doz.png)

Illustrator 2019 shows up in the bar along the bottom:
[AI 2019 looks like it is the target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJNpz.png)

But, then when I run the DeBugger it says CS 6 isn't running and I can't run CC2019?
[Asked to target CS6?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anyZr.png)

Using MacOS 10.12.6
VSCode 1.50.1
ExtendscriptDebugger 1.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the `launch.json` file to set the `targetSpecifier` version number.

For example, for After Effects 2020, I use this configuration to debug.  This object is found in the `configruations` array in the `launch.json` file:

```
{
            "type": "extendscript-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "My app debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Scripts/source.jsx",
            "trace" : true,
            "targetSpecifier": "aftereffects-17.0",
            "engineName": "main",
            "preLaunchTask": "debug-my-app",
            "dontBreakOnErrors" : true
}
```

So, likely you need to find out the value for the `targetSpecifier` for the version of Illustrator you want the debugger to target.

Comment: I do have the tagetSpedifier set:  "illustrator-23.064"
 Every time I run the script though, it says " CS6 isn't running" - CS6 isn't even installed on my computer.(It used to be)  For some reason it's still showing up as installed?

Comment: My suggestion is to uninstall the ExtendScript Debugger plugin from VSCode, then re-install it.  Don't just "Disable" it, actually uninstall it and try again.  I'm thinking there are some files that the ExtendScript debugger needs to reset since you once has CS6 installed but now you don't.